# Image From Android to MySQL Blob

Tags: php, android, mysql, imageview, blob

Good day everybody! As the title say, I try to load an Image from an ImageView to MySQL. I want to save it like a Blob in MySQL.

I have seen several questions about this but no answers in my case: I still remain stuck!

Following is my XML ImageView:

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/das_photoib"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:maxWidth = "150dp"
                    android:maxHeight="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Following is my JAVA activity

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.devenirassistant, container, false);
photoprofil = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.das_photoib);
```

In the same activity, when I want to upload the picture, I put it in a ContentValues:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)photoprofil.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
cv.put("image", Arrays.toString(b));
```

Then I call an AsyncTask which call a php file itself with the contentValues as parameter.
In the php file I get the "image" data and I try to load it in the MySQL "image" row of a table "image_personne", which has been define as "BLOB". I do it like this:

```
    if (isset($_POST['image'])){
                $image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($_POST['image']));

                $request5 = "INSERT INTO image_personne (id_personne, isDeleted, image, isModere) VALUES ({$_POST['id']}, '0', $image, 0)";

$result5 = mysqli_query($connexion,$request5) or die(mysqli_error($connexion));
            }
```

There are no errors out, but that doesn't load! Could you help me to debug? Thank you!

---

This, is what is done now:

Android side:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)photoprofil.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
cv.put("image", Base64.encode(b,Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Php side:

```
$request5 = "INSERT INTO image_personne (id_personne, isDeleted, image, isModere) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

            $image = $_POST['image'];
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $del = '0';
            $mod = '0';
            $stmt = $connexion->prepare($request5); //prepare the statements
            $stmt->bind_param("isbi", $id, $del, $null, $mod ); //bind parameter
            $stmt->send_long_data(0, $image);   //add blob data to statement
            $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Now, because I correct one part (see the other answer), it looks like it is in php. I don't know how to transform my byte[] in blob

Answer (score 0):

This will work,save it as `byte[]` array not as `Array.toString()`

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)photoprofil.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
cv.put("image", b);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have tried, and it returns an error on the php file: Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image. So I guess I have to delete imagecreatefromstring and write only: $image = base64_decode($_POST['image']); But it returns another error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?w?5, 0)' at line 1. I guess the image format is not good. Do you know what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your php side. Here I assume, `$_POST['image']` as the file input in `base64_encode` encoded format. So we will insert it as base64 encoded format to database as blob. Also will use

1. We receive data as base64_encod format
2. Save it in database as blob
3. retrieve the data and decode the image create from string

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['image']))  {    $request5 = "INSERT INTO image_personne (id_personne, isDeleted, image,sModere)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)";  //statement for db update
       $image = $_POST['image'];     //assign image the received data
       $id = $_POST['id'];   //assign values to variables
       $isdel = '0';
       $ismod = 0;
       $stmt = $connexion->prepare($request5); //prepare the statements
       $stmt->bind_param("isbi", $id, $isdel, $null, $ismod ); //bind parameter
       $stmt->send_long_data(0, $image);   //add blob data to statement
       $stmt->execute();  //execute the statement
       }
   ```

Update:

```
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); 
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
```

You can try this method for image file to string conversion.

Comment: Ok I tried, but the image is null now when I insert in mysql...Didn't you do an error on this: "bind_param("isbi", $id, $isdel, $null, $ismod );"? Isn't it $image instead of $null? Thx

Comment: $stmt->send_long_data(0, $image);  this will add your data to db during execution. By the way can you show the data sending code/sending data type. @dam

Comment: But how does php know where to send $image in send_long_data? Indeed, it can be the first field, the second field, the third...or is it detect by the place where you have put "$null" in bind_param? In MySQL: id_personne is INT(11), isDeleted is TINYINT(1), image is BLOB and isModere is TINYINT(1)

Comment: No. In bind parameters, b used for blob. Send long data applies only for blob. No need of worry on this code, tested on local host and also on public server.

Comment: Weird because that doesn't work. It fills all others fields but leave image to null :( I don't understand why!

Comment: I have wroten it after the end of my question :) The dataType for the image is a byte array like in the answer of rajan ks. After, on Php file I just do this: $image = base64_encode($_POST['image'])

Comment: I have edited my previous post while you were posting. Is it the information you need?

Comment: I have edited first message with the code. @Subin Thomas

Comment: @dam check my answer update. I prefer you to send base64 encoded string to server. And insert it to db without decoding. This will work.

Comment: Sorry but no :-((( I have copied your code exactly, but I just changed this: Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr) which doesn't exist I think by this: Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT). But it is the same

Comment: Oh no.. Then move to namevalue pair and send the string with post method. @dam

Comment: It's how I was doing first: all my project was with namevaluepair instead of contentvalues it wasn't working neither... :( Very weird all this

Comment: I worked with namevalue pair and everything was fine in both directions.